# Spring @PropertySources value not overriding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am deploying my Spring Boot application as a WAR file in Tomcat. I was expecting my application-local.properties to override values that also exist in my application.properties file. But it seems that the values from application-local.properties are only read if those keys do not exist in the application.properties. My application.properties file is located in src/main/resources/ of my project and application-local.properties is located in ${catalina.home}/property_files/com/demo/config folder

context.xml

```
<Parameter name="spring.profiles.active" value="local" override="false"/>
```

catalina.properties

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/property_files
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:com/demo/config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

EDIT 1: Actually, my environment dependent property file is being loaded. But it does not override any values from the internal property file.

EDIT 2: Thanks for all your suggestions. But I discovered that my problem was caused by directory precedence. Turns out that property files on the root classpath has higher precedence than any property files regardless of the order in which they are declared.

Comment: Basically, I just want to use the src/main/resources/application.properties for local development where values can be overridden by another property file on a different environment (dev integration, QA, uat, production).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using many propertySource annotation try setting while starting application

`java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location={your_location}/application.properties,classpath:/override.properties.`

Whatever you provide as part of commandline will be of the highest
precedence.
**Or Do something like this and test**

```java
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class DefaultConfiguration {}
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:{environment_specific_property_name}.properties")
    public class EnvironmentSpecific{

        @Configuration
        @Import(DefaultConfiguration .class)
        static class Configuration {}

    }
```

Comment: Good practice is removing all the property file from classpath and keep it in a {specific_config_location} and provide the location to spring during server startup like I have mentioned earlier

Comment: Actually, my environment dependent property file is being loaded. But it does not override any values from the internal property file.

Comment: Your solution would probably work. But I discovered that my problem was caused by directory precedence. Turns out that property files on the root classpath has higher precedence than any property files regardless of the order in which they are declared.

Comment: Nice observation but you should not have such kind of constraints affecting the behavior of project.Try to remove these anomalies in the beginning stage of project.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of application.properties, place your default configuration / properties in a different file. It seems property values defined in application.properties has the highest precedence.

So, something like this will work:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-env.properties")
@PropertySource(value="file:${application.home}/application-env.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
public class GlobalSettings {
  //configuration values
}
```

Tested in Spring 4.x and Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your suggestions. But I discovered that my problem was caused by directory precedence. Turns out that property files on the root classpath has higher precedence than any property files regardless of the order in which they are declared.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("file:${catalina.base}/property_files/com/demo/config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

This should work if file actually located at specified place and will get required values.

Comment: Actually, my environment dependent property file is being loaded. But it does not override any values from the internal property file.

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("file:${catalina.home}/property_files/com/demo/config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Untested

Comment: It did not work. I believe that the profile dependent property file was already added to the classpath when I declared shared.loader=${catalina.home}/property_files on my catalina.properties. Actually, I don't encounter any issue when I delete any conflicting entry on the application.properties. I was just expecting the same keys to be overridden

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration to override the properties from your `application.properties` in the class path with an external `application.properties` file, 
ignore the later if no such file present, note the `order` parameter, you can set the priority order if there are multiple files.

```
<!--load from external file first-->
<context:property-placeholder order="1" ignore-resource-not-found="true" 
        location="file:/path_to/your_app/application.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
<!--load any properties not found in file from class path-->
<context:property-placeholder order="2"  
        location="classpath:application.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Comment: Can this be done with annotations?